# What do $< and $@ represent in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Can anybody please explain the meaning of `$<` and `$@` in a `Makefile`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the makefile symbols $@ and $< mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`$<` evaluates to the first "prerequisite" in the make rule, and `$@` evaluates to the "target" in the make rule.

Here's an example:

```
file.o : file.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

In this case, `$<` will be replaced with `file.c` and `$@` will be `file.o`.

These are more useful in generic rules like this:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

See [this manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) for more info.

Comment: Note that while the above two examples will work with GNU Make, they are not portable.  POSIX doesn't define % rules, and it defines $< only for suffix rules (i.e., as Laurence Gonslaves showed in his answer).

The standard definitions of these variables are better read here :
http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html

Comment: On the other hand, writing Makefiles becomes so much easier if you restrict yourself to GNU make. (which is portable to more or less any all existing platforms)

Comment: (...waiting for someone to tell me which platforms GNU make is not available on...)

Comment: They are also important when using VPATH, since they will expand to the directory in which the source file was found.

Answer (score 7):

`$@` is the target of the current rule.
`$<` is the name of the first prerequisite ("source") of the current rule.

So for example:

```
.c.o:
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

This will expand to a command something like:

```
gcc -c -Wall -o foo.o foo.c
```

See also the [GNU make manual § 10.5.3, "Automatic Variables"](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables).

Comment: What if you have multiple source files for a single target?

Comment: @MarcusJ As mentioned in the answer, `$<` is the name of the *first* prerequisite. You can follow the link in the answer for other automatic variables (`$?`, `$^`, `$+`, `$|`) that will give you more than just the first prerequisite.