# What do the makefile symbols $@ and $< mean?

Tags: makefile

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

What do the `$@` and `$<` do exactly?

Comment: The link above is broken, here is the another one: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html

Comment: The ".cpp.o:" means building ".o" (object files) from ".cpp" (source files)

Comment: I feel it should be noted there is a make tutorial at the following link from which I believe Mohit obtained the makefile in his post.
http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

Comment: Microsoft calls it [Filename Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/filename-macros?view=vs-2019)(for NMAKE) which is clearer than [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html)(for MAKE). It's useful to see both sides for educational purposes.

Comment: @user2188550, both sides of what?

Answer (score 805, accepted):

`$@` is the name of the target being generated, and `$<` the first prerequisite (usually a source file). You can find a list of all these special variables in the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables).

For example, consider the following declaration:

```
all: library.cpp main.cpp
```

In this case:

- `$@` evaluates to `all`
- `$<` evaluates to `library.cpp`
- `$^` evaluates to `library.cpp main.cpp`

Comment: It's worth noting that `$@` does not necessarily have to end up being a file, it could also be the name of a `.PHONY` target.

Comment: Can I add to commandline options this: `$@s` to generate assembly-output such as name.os?

Comment: Beware when the first dependency is a variable representing a list, $< is evaluated after it is expanded. So when LIST = lib1.cpp lib2.cpp, and all: ${LIST} main.cpp, $< is evaluated to just lib1.cpp. A few years ago, I had spend some time figuring out what's happend in the result caused by this behaviour.

Comment: In general $@ refers to the target name which is to the left side of the :

Comment: If anyone has enough rep to make a 1-character change, the http:// link in the above post now redirects to an https:// link and should be updated.

Comment: These are only true for GNU Make. On BSD Make `$<` refers to the implied source in a suffix transformation rule, and is not defined at all for explicit rules. `$^` isn't defined at all, that functionality is given by either `${.ALLSRC}` or `$>`.

Comment: instead of `$<` and `$^`, wouldn't this just be a lot more readable if these were treated the same way bash arguments are treated (`$1` `$2`, ...)?

Comment: Any clue what double `$$` differ? E.g. `$$@` or `$$<`

Answer (score 148):

From [Managing Projects with GNU Make, 3rd Edition, p. 16](http://uploads.mitechie.com/books/Managing_Projects_with_GNU_Make_Third_Edition.pdf) (it's under *GNU Free Documentation License*):

> *Automatic variables* are set by `make` after a rule is matched. They
>   provide access to elements from the target and prerequisite lists so
>   you don’t have to explicitly specify any filenames. They are very
>   useful for avoiding code duplication, but are critical when defining
>   more general pattern rules.
>
> There are seven “core” automatic variables:
>
> - `$@`: The filename representing the target.
> - `$%`: The filename element of an archive member specification.
> - `$<`: The filename of the first prerequisite.
> - `$?`: The names of all prerequisites that are newer than the target,
>     separated by spaces.
> - `$^`: The filenames of all the prerequisites, separated by spaces. This
>     list has duplicate filenames removed since for most uses, such as
>     compiling, copying, etc., duplicates are not wanted.
> - `$+`: Similar to `$^`, this is the names of all the prerequisites separated
>     by spaces, except that `$+` includes duplicates. This variable was
>     created for specific situations such as arguments to linkers where
>     duplicate values have meaning.
> - `$*`: The stem of the target filename. A stem is typically a filename
>     without its suffix. Its use outside of pattern rules is
>     discouraged.
>
> In addition, each of the above variables has two variants for
>   compatibility with other makes. One variant returns only the directory
>   portion of the value. This is indicated by appending a “D” to the
>   symbol, `$(@D)`, `$(<D)`, etc. The other variant returns only the file
>   portion of the value. This is indicated by appending an “F” to the
>   symbol, `$(@F)`, `$(<F)`, etc. Note that these variant names are more than
>   one character long and so must be enclosed in parentheses. GNU make
>   provides a more readable alternative with the dir and notdir
>   functions.

Answer (score 104):

The `$@` and `$<` are called *automatic variables*. The variable `$@` represents the name of the target and `$<` represents the first prerequisite required to create the output file.
For example:

```
hello.o: hello.c hello.h
         gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Here, `hello.o` is the output file. This is what `$@` expands to. The first dependency is `hello.c`. That's what `$<` expands to.

The `-c` flag generates the `.o` file; see `man gcc` for a more detailed explanation. The `-o` specifies the output file to create.

For further details, you can read [this article on linoxide about Linux Makefiles](https://linoxide.com/how-tos/learn-linux-makefiles/).

Also, you can check the [GNU  `make` manuals](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html#SEC_Contents). It will make it easier to make Makefiles and to debug them.

If you run this command, it will output the makefile database:

```
make -p
```

Comment: Your answer sounds like `$<` will expand to `hello.c hello.h` (both). Please, clarify.

Comment: Yes, it will include both hello.c and hello.h

Comment: `$<` is just the first item. To include all, use `$^`.

Comment: Dr Beco is right. The author should modify his answer.

Answer (score 45):

The `$@` and `$<` are special macros.

Where:

`$@` is the file name of the target.

`$<` is the name of the first dependency.

Answer (score 29):

The Makefile builds the `hello` executable if any one of `main.cpp`, `hello.cpp`, `factorial.cpp` changed. The smallest possible Makefile to achieve that specification could have been:

```
hello: main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
    g++ -o hello main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
```

- pro: very easy to read
- con: maintenance nightmare, duplication of the C++ dependencies
- con: efficiency problem, we recompile all C++ even if only one was changed

To improve on the above, we only compile those C++ files that were edited. Then, we just link the resultant object files together.

```
OBJECTS=main.o hello.o factorial.o

hello: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o hello $(OBJECTS)

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp
```

- pro: fixes efficiency issue
- con: new maintenance nightmare, potential typo on object files rules

To improve on this, we can replace all object file rules with a single `.cpp.o` rule:

```
OBJECTS=main.o hello.o factorial.o

hello: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -o hello $(OBJECTS)

.cpp.o:
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

- pro: back to having a short makefile, somewhat easy to read

Here the `.cpp.o` rule defines how to build `anyfile.o` from `anyfile.cpp`.

- `$<` matches to first dependency, in this case, `anyfile.cpp`
- `$@` matches the target, in this case, `anyfile.o`.

The other changes present in the Makefile are:

- Making it easier to changes compilers from g++ to any C++ compiler.
- Making it easier to change the compiler options.
- Making it easier to change the linker options.
- Making it easier to change the C++ source files and output.
- Added a default rule 'all' which acts as a quick check to ensure all your source files are present before an attempt to build your application is made.

Answer (score 2):

in exemple if you want to compile sources but have objects in an different directory :

You need to do :

```
gcc -c -o <obj/1.o> <srcs/1.c> <obj/2.o> <srcs/2.c> ...
```

but with most of macros the result will be all objects followed by all sources, like :

```
gcc -c -o <all OBJ path> <all SRC path>
```

so this will not compile anything ^^ and you will not be able to put your objects files in a different dir :(

the solution is to use these special macros

```
$@ $<
```

this will generate a .o file (obj/file.o) for each .c file in SRC (src/file.c)

```
$(OBJ):$(SRC)
   gcc -c -o $@ $< $(HEADERS) $(FLAGS)
```

it means :

```
    $@ = $(OBJ)
    $< = $(SRC)
```

but lines by lines INSTEAD of all lines of OBJ followed by all lines of SRC

Comment: What is the content you putted in the variables OBJ, SRC and HEADERS? @Aominé