# Makefile trouble, clarification needed

Tags: makefile

The following is the Makefile i use. All is well, except for .o should be created in obj/ directory and it's not.

What am i doing wrong please?

[image]

After making sure that

- src directory contains a.cpp
- target directory exists and is empty
- obj directory exists and is empty

When `make` is ran, i see

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall -c src/a.cpp  -o /Users/me/Dropbox/dev/c++/hott/obj/src/a.o
```

when it should be

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall -c src/a.cpp  -o /Users/me/Dropbox/dev/c++/hott/obj/a.o
```

**What am i doing wrong please?**

**UPDATE**: Nothing seems to change when hardcoding path and not relying on `pwd` resolution

Comment: Hey, the image is not displayed anymore - could you please maybe upload it or smth so that others could see it too??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `-o` you have to specify the filename, not just the output path.  Try:

```
$(CC) $(FLAGS) $(SOURCES) $(OBJ)/$@
```

This question may help, too:

- [What do the makefile symbols $@ and $< mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean)

Also, you may want to call `FLAGS` something like `CFLAGS`, meaning "the flags for compilation".

---

**Edit**

Note that you are not using make efficiently, because you are always recompiling all your .o files from your .cpp files. You should instead use a [Pattern Rule](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html#SEC98), so that Make can have rules to only build what is necessary. (ie. "To build any .o file from a .cpp file, do this: ___")

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

You could edit this to include `$(OBJ)` before the `$@`.

Comment: It is currently trying to `g++ -pedantic -Wall -c src/a.cpp -o obj//src/a.o`, where `obj//src` does not exist.

Comment: You need to change SOURCES to not have the path in front. Maybe cd first in your shell command.

Comment: Try `SOURCES = $(shell cd src && echo *.cpp)` and replace your usage of `$(SOURCES)` with `src/$(SOURCES)`.

Comment: Same deal, `src` appears out of somewhere, updated scripts on top

Answer (score 0):

All is ok when used like this. A small modification from what Jonathon suggested

[image]

Comment: All is *not* okay. You have no dependencies listed for $(OBJECTS), so they will never get re-built.