# Makefile: How do I use variables in the left hand side of the rule?

Tags: variables, makefile

Let's say I want to rewrite this:

```
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp
```

in a more generic way as something like this:

```
SOURCES = main factorial hello

$(SOURCES).o: $(SOURCES).cpp
    g++ -c $(SOURCES).cpp
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the target is. I just want to make this more flexible/generic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First we tell the compiler how to nme the output files, just to avoid misunderstanding:

```
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp -o factorial.o

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp -o hello.o
```

Then we put in [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables), to reduce redundancy:

```
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

Then we realize that these rules all look the same, so we combine them as a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
main.o factorial.o hello.o: %.o : %.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

Then we use a variable to store the names of the objects:

```
OBJECTS := main.o factorial.o hello.o

$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.cpp
    g++ -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: You don't need a static pattern rule.  You can just use the built-in pattern rules.  A one-line makefile `all: main.o factorial.o hello.o` is all you need.

Comment: @MadScientist: True. (In fact, since the the original makefile had no `all` rule, I can replace it with a one-*word* makefile `main.o:`.) But using the built-in rules like that kind of defeats the purpose of the question, which was to show how to use a variable as a target.