# What does "$(@:%.o=%.d)" mean in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I see below command options for GCC in a makefile:

```
... -MMD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT "$(@:%.o=%.d)"  -o "$@" "$<"
```

How to interpret it?

I searched through the makefile document, but no luck so far.

(This is not just about [Automatic Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do the makefile symbols $@ and $< mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean)

Comment: This is not just about Automatic Variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`$(:=)` performs a [string replacement](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html).
`$@` is [the name of the file being generated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220288/3233393) (the target).
So `$(@:%.o=%.d)` is the name of the file, with the `.o` extension changed to `.d`.

This command line generates one `.d` dependency file for each `.o` file.

Comment: I never expected that `()` can interleave with `$@`.

Comment: @smwikipedia Make does not have the prettiest syntax, I'll give you that :p

Answer (score 3):

(Thanks to @Quentin's clue. I just found it!)

It is called [Substitution Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html#Substitution-Refs)

Some quote:

> A substitution reference substitutes the value of a variable with
>   alterations that you specify. It has the form ‘`$(var:a=b)`’ (or
>   ‘`${var:a=b}`’) and its meaning is to take the value of the variable
>   var, replace every a at the end of a word with b in that value, and
>   substitute the resulting string.
>
> When we say “at the end of a word”, we mean that a must appear either
>   followed by whitespace or at the end of the value in order to be
>   replaced; other occurrences of a in the value are unaltered. For
>   example:
>
> `foo := a.o b.o c.o`
>
> `bar := $(foo:.o=.c)`
>
> sets ‘`bar`’ to ‘`a.c b.c c.c`’. See [Setting Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting).
>
> A substitution reference is actually an abbreviation for use of the
>   `patsubst` expansion function (see [Functions for String Substitution and
>   Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions)). We provide substitution references as well as patsubst for
>   compatibility with other implementations of make.

So, the full interpretation of the following command:

```
... -MMD -MP -MF "$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT "$(@:%.o=%.d)"  -o "$@" "$<"
```

is:

> Use gcc to compile the 1st prerequisite file (`$<`) and generate the
>   output file named after the current rule target's name (`%@`). And by
>   the way, generate a makefile named as `*.d` containing a **rule** to describe the  dependency of current rule target. And change the name of **rule** target in the
>   generated `*.d` makefile from `*.o` to `*.d`.