# How do I make multiple targets from a set of templates for the source?

Tags: makefile

I have targets identified by a version number (7.0 7.1 7.2)

I have some templates that have a placeholder that needs to be replaced for each version such that I end up with a directory for each version with all the files in each directory having the appropriate replacements.

So, if the template directory is :

```
template\Dockerfile
```

I want to end up with :

```
7.0\Dockerfile
7.1\Dockerfile
7.2\Dockerfile
```

with the the tag in the `template\Dockerfile` being replaced with the version number.

This is a simplified example. There are actually 4 files in the template folder (and 2 are in a subdirectory).

A pipeline will run `make build-targets` and then the appropriate docker commands to build the containers and push them to the repository - that's the goal.

Whilst it would be nice to have an answer to all of this, I would like to learn, but I can't find anything about how to deal with sets of sources and sets of targets.

Any advice would be appreciated.

### More details in response to comments

The versions are currently just 1 line in the Makefile: `VERSIONS := 7.0 7.1 7.2 latest`

The code to run will be a series of `sed` commands to take a template and replace a `#version#` tag in the file with the version number (except for `latest` in which case it will just remove the tag.

The template sources are all in the `templates` directory. As part of the `sed` command, the resulting filename will have the part `templates` replaced with the version (including `latest`).

A start ... (no idea if this is good or not - still learning)

```
VERSIONS  := 7.0 7.1 7.2 latest
SOURCEDIR := ./templates
DESTDIR   := ./
TEMPLATES := $(shell find $(SOURCEDIR) -type f)

# For each file in $(TEMPLATES) for each version in $(VERSIONS), create a corresponding file in $(DEST_DIR)/$(VERSION)
# Replace `#version#` with $(VERSION) in each file, except for the `latest` target where the `#version#` removed.
```

Based upon solutions provide below, my final code is:

```
VERSIONS := 7.0 7.1 7.2 latest
SOURCE_DIR := ./templates
TEMPLATES := $(shell find $(SOURCE_DIR) -type f)
TEMPLATES := $(patsubst $(SOURCE_DIR)/%,%,$(TEMPLATES))
DEST_DIR := ./

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
.PHONY: all

# $(1): version
# $(2): template file (without the $(SOURCE_DIR)/ stem)
define generate_target_file
$(DEST_DIR)/$(1)/$(2): $(SOURCE_DIR)/$(2)
    @echo "Making $$@"
    @mkdir -p $$(dir $$@)
    @if [ "$(1)" == "latest" ]; then \
        sed 's/#version#//g' $$< > $$@; \
    else \
        sed 's/#version#/$(1)-/g' $$< > $$@; \
    fi

all: $(DEST_DIR)/$(1)/$(2)
endef

$(foreach version,$(VERSIONS),$(foreach template,$(TEMPLATES),$(eval $(call generate_target_file,$(version),$(template)))))

list:
    @echo 'The following targets are available :'
    @$(MAKE) -pRrq -f $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) : 2>/dev/null | \
        awk -v RS= -F: '/^# File/,/^# Finished Make data base/ {if ($$1 !~ "^[#.]") {print $$1}}' | \
        sort | \
        egrep -v -e '^[^[:alnum:]]' -e '^$@$$' | \
        xargs -0
```

Comment: As usual with make, things are much easier if you already know how to do what you want to automate on the Command Line Interface (CLI). Can you show: 1) where the list of version numbers come from? 2) what you would do on the CLI for a version number?

Comment: I've added some more comments to the question. The bit I can't work out is how to (or if I should) define all the targets (every `$(TEMPLATE)` for every `$(VERSION)`).

Comment: Your question is now much clearer. See my answer for a GNU-make starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GNU-make, you can easily create loops with make's `foreach` function. And you can nest them. The `eval` function can be used to programmatically instantiate make constructs and the `call` function allows you to create kind of macros:

```
V := 7.0 7.1 7.2 latest
S := ./templates
T := $(shell find $(S) -type f)
T := $(patsubst $(S)/%,%,$(T))
D := ./destdir

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all
.PHONY: all

# $(1): version
# $(2): template file (without the $(S)/ stem)
# $(3): replacement string
define MY_rule
$(D)/$(1)/$(2): $(S)/$(2)
    mkdir -p $$(dir $$@)
    sed 's/#version#/$(3)/g' $$< > $$@

all: $(D)/$(1)/$(2)
endef

$(foreach v,$(V),\
  $(foreach t,$(T),\
    $(eval $(call MY_rule,$(v),$(t),$(patsubst latest,,$(v))))))
```

The [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) explains how this works. Beware the double expansion of the `MY_rule` macro, reason why some `$` signs must be doubled.

Comment: I didn't quite understand the `$$< > $$@` bit initially, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean helped there.

Thank you.