# How to use Makefile from a very simple example

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to learn how Makefile works, so I decided to try it with a very simple code. This is what I wrote:

```
/* justify.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "line.h"
#include "word.h"

int main(void) {
    printf("I'm in the main.\n");
    read_word();
    write_line();
}
```

```
/* line.h */

void write_line(void);
```

```
/* line.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "line.h"

void write_line(void) {
    printf("write_line\n");
}
```

```
/* word.h */

void read_word(void);
```

```
/* word.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "word.h"

void read_word(void) {
    printf("read_word\n");
}
```

now ... if I do everything from the terminal it works:

```
> gcc -c justify.c
> gcc -c line.c
> gcc -c word.c
> gcc -o justify justify.c line.c word.c
```

but if I try to do everything with a Makefile it gives me an error:

```
# Makefile 

justify: justify.o line.o word.o
    gcc -o justify.o line.o word.o

justify.o: justify.c line.h word.h
    gcc -c justify.c

line.o: line.c line.h
    gcc -c line.c

word.o: word.c word.h
    gcc -c word.c
```

```
> make justify

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You should add include guards to the `*.h` files and remove them from the dependencies in the makefile. Not that it is related to your problem though

Comment: `gcc -o justify.o line.o word.o` -> `gcc -o justify justify.o line.o word.o`

Comment: check the `gcc -o` line. should that not be `gcc -o justify justify.o line.o word.o`

Comment: Thanks, everyone, including you Eugene Sh. The 'include guards' are very interesting.

Comment: The issue that @tkausl pointed out, while valid, would not explain the message you're seeing, so something else is going on..   It looks like line.o was compiled for another architecture.   Do an `objdump -f line.o`.   Then delete the .o file, and recompile from the command line and check again.    If the makefile is producing different output than the command line, then try running `which gcc` from both your shell and a makefile recipe to see if there's an issue with the path.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry `would not explain the message you're seeing` It does since neither `line.o` nor `word.o` contain the main function.

Comment: Ahh yes, I stand corrected.

Comment: @tkausl Yours would be the solution to my problem, what should I do to confirm that it is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

No pun intended, but you are making make a bit harder than it needs to be. In your case with the source and headers all in the same directory, it is quite simple to use wildcards to allow make to handle the rest. For example with three simple variable declartions in your `Makefile`, you can tell make what your sources are, your includes and how to generate an object file for each of the source files that isn't the application name.

For starters, specify your application name:

```
# application name
APPNAME := justify
```

If needed, set your compiler variables, e.g.

```
# compiler
CC      := gcc
CCLD    := $(CC)
```

Now make knows your application name is held in `APPNAME` which you access like any other variable in a `Makefile` as `$(APPNAME)`.

Now just use `wildcard` to collect all sources and includes in variables as well, and let `make` associate the object file output:

```
# source/include/object variables
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)
```

Set your compiler/linker/library flags:

```
# compiler and linker flags
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -finline-functions -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast
LDFLAGS :=
# libraries
LIBS    :=
```

Now create your default target for `make` (**note:** there must be a *tab-character* `'\t'` in front of each rule):

```
all:    $(OBJECTS)
    $(CCLD) -o $(APPNAME) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

A rule to compile all sources to objects:

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

(see: [What do the makefile symbols $@ and $< mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean) for explanation of the automatic variables used)

And finally a target for `clean:`

```
clean:
    rm -rf $(APPNAME) *.o
```

A complete example for your files would be:

```
# application name
APPNAME := justify
# compiler
CC      := gcc
CCLD    := $(CC)
# compiler and linker flags
CFLAGS  := -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -finline-functions -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast
LDFLAGS :=
# libraries
LIBS    :=
# source/include/object variables
SOURCES := $(wildcard *.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard *.h)
OBJECTS := $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

# target for all
all:    $(OBJECTS)
    $(CCLD) -o $(APPNAME) $(OBJECTS) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)
# strip only if -DDEBUG not set
ifneq ($(debug),-DDEBUG)
    strip -s $(APPNAME)
endif

$(OBJECTS): %.o : %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(APPNAME) *.o
```

(**note:** a rule to `strip` the executable was also added to the `all:` target)

**Example Build**

With your `Makefile` source and include files in a common directory, e.g.

```
$ ll
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 668 Nov  6 12:38 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 161 Nov  6 12:31 justify.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 106 Nov  6 12:32 line.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  37 Nov  6 12:31 line.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 104 Nov  6 12:32 word.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  36 Nov  6 12:32 word.h
```

Just type `make` to have your application built:

```
$ make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -finline-functions -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast -c -o word.o word.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -finline-functions -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast -c -o line.o line.c
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -finline-functions -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast -c -o justify.o justify.c
gcc -o justify word.o line.o justify.o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -finline-functions -std=c11 -Wshadow -Ofast
strip -s justify
```

No errors, you can check all files were created as expected:

```
$ ll
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  668 Nov  6 12:38 Makefile
-rwxr-xr-x 1 david david 6312 Nov  6 13:01 justify
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  161 Nov  6 12:31 justify.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1760 Nov  6 13:01 justify.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  106 Nov  6 12:32 line.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   37 Nov  6 12:31 line.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1496 Nov  6 13:01 line.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david  104 Nov  6 12:32 word.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david   36 Nov  6 12:32 word.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 david david 1496 Nov  6 13:01 word.o
```

Test your executable:

```
$ ./justifiy
I'm in the main.
read_word
write_line
```

Lastly, clean your build directory with `make clean`, e.g.

```
$ make clean
```

And confirm all build files are removed.

That's about the easiest way to go about writing minimal make files. You can list each object individually and the required includes to support them, but why? the automatic variables will take care of that for you. There is much, much more you can do with Makefiles, but for getting started, this will make your life easier.

Comment: difficult to find better explanation...

Answer (score 1):

You can heavily simplify the `Makefile` you have. Make provides lots of helpful variables.

```
$@ - target name
$< - first prequisite
$^ - all prequsites
```

```
justify: justify.o line.o word.o
        gcc -o $@ $^    # this one will turn into
                        # gcc -o justify justify.o line.o word.o 

justify.o: justify.c
        gcc -c $<       # this one will turn into
                        # gcc -c justify.c

line.o: line.c
        gcc -c $<

word.o: word.c
        gcc -c $<
```

it's also a good idea to add `clean`

```
clean:
        -rm *.o justify
```

```
-rm - minus sign at the beginning will not produce error if command fails;   
      useful in case you expect that something might be missing
```

Answer (score 0):

There is bug in your make file. The commands for the make target `justify:` are missing the output file name. It should be like this.

```
gcc -o justify justify.o line.o word.o
```

with your current command line the gcc will try to output justify.o by linking line.o and word.o and the it does not find `_main` which is not defined in line.o and word.o

The make command already knows how to convert a `.c` file to `.o` so you do not need to tell this to make again in the make file. Keeping this in mind, the following make file is enough for your test case.

```
# Makefile 
justify: justify.o line.o word.o
    gcc -o justify justify.o line.o word.o
```

You can further simplify this by using make's built-in automatic variables. `$@` and `$^`. The `$@` variable contains the name of the target of rule. and `$^` contains the name of all the prerequisites of the rule. So using these two variables your make file will be.

```
justify: justify.o line.o word.o
        gcc -o $@ $^
```