# In a Makefile, what does ">" mean?

Tags: c, makefile, syntax

for example: ./main 45 M > mul1.out, in this situation does > mean save the output of the program to a file called mul1.out or does it use mul1.out as the input of the program?

I believe > means it saves the output of the program to the file

Comment: Tip: To a bit of research on ‘redirecting’ output to a file.

Comment: `>` saves output to a file. `<` loads a file as input to your program.

Comment: This is really a question about shell syntax.  Make doesn't run commands itself, it invokes a POSIX shell (`sh`) to run the commands, so the syntax of commands is described there.  You can google for "shell redirection" or whatever to find more details.

Comment: For completeness, there is also a meaning for `<` in makefiles that is not a redirect. More specifically, `$<` is the first prerequisite to a make target. Reference this answer for more (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220277/what-do-the-makefile-symbols-and-mean)

Answer (score 0):

Using the `>` symbol, you are writing the output of the `./main` program to a file `mul1.out` instead of the `stdout`.

[Read more](https://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_05_01.html) on input/output redirection in Linux.