# What does $< (dollar sign + left trianglular bracket) mean in a makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am trying to understand a simple command-line string that executes Javac and passes it some simple arguments.  The complete command line is:

```
javac -d $(OUTPATH) -sourcepath $(SOURCEPATH) $<
```

Everything in this line is straightforward and understandable to me except for the final tokens: `$<`.

What do these tokens mean?

ADDENDUM:  Indeed, the commenters are correct.  This line occurs within a makefile.  It is obvious to me now, but not when I wrote this question, that a makefile is passed to `make` and is not a shell script.

Please note: [What do $< and $@ represent in a Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924652/what-do-and-represent-in-a-makefile) also discusses this (I did not see it when I looked for previous questions about this).

Comment: I don't think this is correct bash syntax.

Comment: I would guess that it is since $< is a special variable in make, and not bash.

Comment: Correct - this occurs in a makefile.  I have added an addendum to clarify this.  Thanks.

Comment: It is unusual to use `make` for Java projects. The de-facto standard build tools for Java are [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) and [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org).

Comment: @Jesper: Thanks for the confirmation about that (though aren't Eclipse projects also nearly 'standard'?).  Note: in my current situation, I am reviewing a pre-existing makefile that is present with the following project: https://github.com/fukuchi/libqrencode (in order to make sure I understand it), prior to building the project directly in NetBeans, perhaps utilizing Maven.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Eclipse is the most used Java IDE, but with Ant or Maven you don't need an IDE to build the project. NetBeans has good built-in Maven support; for Eclipse you'll need to install the m2eclipse plugin for Maven support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like something from a makefile, not a command line.  In that case, `$<` expands to the first prerequisite of the current target.  That is, the `.java` file that the `.class` target depends on.