# What's the meaning of $@?

Tags: shell, unix, gcc

I came across the makefile when I read something about flex

```
  fb3-1: fb3-1.l fb3-1.y fb3-1.h
     bison -d fb3-1.y
     flex -ofb3-1.lex.c fb3-1.l
     cc -o $@ fb3-1.tab.c fb3-1.lex.c fb3-1funcs.c
```

but what's the meaning of $@? Is it in the shell or some argument of gcc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do $< and $@ represent in a Makefile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924652/what-do-and-represent-in-a-makefile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$@` is just short-hand for the file name of the current target (`fb3-1` in this case).

See the [Automatic Variables section](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) of the [gnu make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for full details on this and other useful automatic variables such as `$<`.